# How to first apply like and then limit on SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help with searching MySQL database, I need to apply like to database and than to limit that result. I've implemented and tested both things separately and they work.

My current code I think works reverse from what I need (it applies like only to part of table defined by `LIMIT`) is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (C_NAME='$cl' AND P_NAME='$pr') AND (CLSTOCK LIKE '%$term%') $max");
```

`$term` is the string im geting with post method for searching.

`$max` is string that equals to `'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $pagemax .',' .$pagemax;`

Comment: Could you not have the first section of the code between paranthesis, and on that paranthesis apply the limit code?

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. I still dont understand order of query comands lol. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the first part of the code inside paranthesis, and then use the `LIMIT` clausus on that code, like so:

```
mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((C_NAME='$cl' AND P_NAME='$pr') AND (CLSTOCK LIKE '%$term%')) $max");
```

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
$pagenum=2;
$pagemax=5;
$min=($pagenum - 1) * $pagemax ;
$max=$pagemax ;
$limit=" limit $min,$max";

$result =mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE C_NAME='$cl' AND P_NAME='$pr' AND CLSTOCK LIKE '%$term%'". $limit);
```

Comment: Ok, i did that, (called them $start and $number instead of $min and $max) but its basically same as it was before functionality-wise.

Comment: That was my first code, just formated a bit differently. It only needed paranthesis around whole Where section. WHERE ((C_NAME='$cl' AND P_NAME='$pr') AND (CLSTOCK LIKE '%$term%')).

Comment: please check now ,you dont new any braces

Answer (score 0):

i think  it is due to the braces.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((C_NAME='$cl' AND P_NAME='$pr') AND (CLSTOCK LIKE '%$term%')) limit $min,$max"
```

I think try it.